# Making a plastic card that looks like a credit card with a long-range module inside

Tags: bluetooth, rfid, gps

Does anyone know how I could make a card the size of a credit card with something like a GPS/bluettoth/RFID module that could be detected from a relatively long range. The purpose is to see where this card is on a map for example.

Are there GPS modules that are that small?

If someone could direct me to some tutorials or help.

EDIT: Really the idea is, If I ever lost my wallet for example, I could track where in the house I lost this wallet. A lame example but this is the basic idea.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to be pessimistic and say no. Do feel free to prove me wrong, though. First, how are you going to track the card? Bluetooth has extremely low range. GPS can't be used to actually rack anything, it just gives you your location. RFID may be the right way to go. What is "long range"? How much money do you want to invest into it? How are you going to solve the power problems? RFID could be powered by radio, but the rest are going to need dedicated power sources. I doubt you could make it out of PVC, but maybe two thin PCBs sandwiched together could work

Comment: Quantify what you mean by "a relatively long range". Also, if you could fill in more details in your example use-case, that would help. From reading your question, I'm not clear who is tracking the card, what data communication needs to occur, or what the scale of the map is.

Comment: ok.. well say I lost this fake credit card somewhere in my house and I would want to find it. What kind of range would a RFID module have, and is the almost credit card shape and thickness feasable? Just so you know, I don't have much electronics knowledge, but I do know programming.

Comment: @AndrejaKo Well im not looking necessarily to track it. Although it would be nice, the basic functionanality im looking for is to see only the location of this potential card.

Comment: @Andrei TheGiant Haxtor  After reading your question, I got the idea that you need to track the card. I think that it would be a good idea to put that you need the card to know its location in the question body.

Comment: @Andrei: Using GPS indoors is fraught with peril.  If you do get a signal, it's error would be so large (~10 m) it would be useless.  The best bet would be to have some sort of triangulation like @Adam suggests; you could do it with RFID or more broadly, a radio beacon--like for tracking animals which could be made *very* small and likely thin.

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to make some sort of tracking device that you could find somewhere further than you could throw a ball, RFID and BT are out.

You could take the components commonly found in cell phones and boil it down to only what matters for this application: a GPS module and a cellular radio.  Both could be made quite thin, the limiting factor would essentially be PCB thickness, IC height, RF shielding, and battery.  To access anyone's cell network you will need a SIM card or other method for them to bill you.

Be aware that designing a circuit to be thin (let alone credit-card thin) and with a high level of integration is a very difficult and very costly problem.  There's a reason a Droids and iPhones cost $500+, even when sold by the millions.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked in to this a fair amount for some projects that I was considering. In short, it is possible(ish), but hard. A handful of companies offer solutions doing this intended to track items in warehouses, and they are expensive.

[Here](http://www.rfidtoys.net/forum/forum_posts.asp?TID=139) is a more detailed (although slightly old) discussion on using RFID tags and multiple readers to determine 3-space position of the tag. There have been some advances, but the fundamental theory and difficulties are the same.

The main problem you will run in to if utilizing another solution is power storage. RFID in its various incarnations is the only passive communication technology. You can get much more accurate results from sound or possibly some sort of RF beacon (would be expensive due to the tight timings needed to get accuracy), but you need some sort of battery to run the thing. Batteries are thick, so that probably knocks the "credit card" size out.

Wireless power and low-power micros have come a long way in the last few years, so it might be possible to blast your space in enough power to get something more complex to work. I'm not aware of any wireless power technologies on the market that work at more than inches, but they are coming.

Good luck :)

Comment: The CR2016 coin cell is 1.6mm thick and common.

Answer (score 1):

Is that form factor absolutely necessary?

Consider if instead of a thin card, you could have a small box - smaller than a matchbox. Would it be an option?

I'm asking because Telit has a module that integrates GPS+GSM, and is programmable via python. You only have to add the antennas, a battery and a SIM chip.

http://www.telit.com/en/products/gsm-gprs.php?p_ac=show&p=7

I don't know about other manufactures, but probably Telit isn't the only one to offer such a product.

Answer (score 0):

What's available depends on where you operate and what you can get and are willing to use I suppose. A couple of ideas:

Closest that comes to mind is a modern cellphone with GPS (for locating itself) and GSM/3G/other network for communicating that location. Not quite credit card, but same kind of shape. Imagine the data modem and GPS parts there and it might give you an idea of the complexity and size of that method.

You might also be able to make a small (more or less legal) simple radio beacon (quite slim with SMT) and see if you can track that with RSSI or AOA or other location methods. Reception might be enough for "detecting" it, as the question says.

There are also some microcontroller devkits that carry radios in 400-800-900-2400 MHz bands that might have fair range outdoors (maybe even legally). Bluetooth is clumsy, elaborate and primarily short range.

Then there's also PMR, but I'm not aware of anything smaller than a stripped radio phone / baby monitor for that.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is to track a lost wallet in your house, you could just look for an appendage for a key ring chain that replies when you whistle to it, and put it into your wallet. Then just whistle around the house and it will reply. Cheap and simple.

Answer (score 0):

If you limit yourself to staying indoors and place location beacons around your house, you can track position using ZigBee.

Overview: http://www.smallformfactors.com/articles/id/?3041

App Note: http://focus.ti.com/lit/an/swra095/swra095.pdf

Essentially, you place a bunch of radio beacons in known positions then use the RSSI (Received Signal Strength Indicator) in the mobile node to calculate location.